# How can we add component dynamically from outside app in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-dynamic-components

I have a JSON file outside of my Angular6 app,I want to read that JSON file and attach component in my application at runtime.

Like I am getting

```js
response:[{html:"<dynamic-component></dynamic-component>",component:"
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic-component',
  template: '<span>Hello from dynamic component</span>'
})
export class DynamicComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  
  }

}"
}];
```

Please suggest, anyway in Angular6 I can achieve that type dynamic component loader.

Comment: You can't. Angular code is compiled to JS. you won't be able to append dynamic components like that once your code is compiled.

Comment: any other way to load component from outside? @trichetriche

Comment: You could take a look at that : https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader